# Como consumir webservice (WSDL) correios com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-service

Eu gostaria de utilizar este web-service disponibilizado pelo correio para um pequeno projeto pessoal (de começo, somente o retorno de endereço pelo CEP):
https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl

é possível consumi-lo via javascript (puro ou jquery)?

A unica vez que utilizei web-services foi em uma plataforma que praticamente montava tudo automático.
Aproveitando a pergunta:
Qual a diferença das extensões de WS? notei que algumas são WSDL e outras algo como asmx.

Comment: Minha resposta te ajudou ? deu certo? abs.

Comment: Olha em node: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap  Ainda tem outras LIbs que pode usar em js

Answer (score 2):

Você tem muitas opções, com JSON (mais prático e fácil) ficaria assim (usando JQuery), no meu exemplo estou usando o VIACEP, funciona bem também :)

```
$.getJSON('https://viacep.com.br/ws/11441080/json/', function(data) {         
    //informações do endereço (objeto data)
});
```

Html completo:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>JqueryCEP</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $.getJSON('https://viacep.com.br/ws/11441080/json/', function(data) {
       var bairro = data.bairro;
       alert(bairro); 
});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        JqueryCEP :)
    </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Esses que retornam um Json realmente são mais práticos, porem eu gostaria de aprender a utilizar e manipular o próprio do correio.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que a documentação oficial vai responder suas perguntas. São só 32 páginas; e você pedrá baixar e ler em PDF. Tem tudo que você precisa para montar seu sistema. O melhor de tudo é que é oficial: diretamente dos Correios.

Link: [Clique aqui](http://blog.correios.com.br/correioslog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Correios-Web-Service-Padr%C3%B5es-T%C3%A9cnicos-de-Comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-Servi%C3%A7o-e-fulfillment_v2-5.pdf)